# Problem with Digikam in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: digikam

I was using Digikam on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 17.04.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, I was able to install Digikam by logging into Ubuntu on Xorg and using Synaptic, but the application is not fully functional. It lacks for example of the extensions for exportation, and the home page  is not complete, lacking the upper bar of commands.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This is only half an answer, so will not help 100%.
DigiKam is a `KDE` package, not a `Gnome` package. Which means there are a bunch of dependencies that need to be installed as well. I am sure you've done this. However, and here is the crunch, not all of these packages may be `Wayland` friendly.
The last version of Digi' was September, so may not include Wayland support.
The DigiKam FAQ talks about support for `X`, but nothing about `Wayland`. 
See also the FAQ for other Ubuntu items.
https://www.digikam.org/documentation/FAQ/

Answer (score 1):

To bring up the missing upper bar of commands you might press Ctrl+M, which gives access to the preferences and configuration menu.
Now there is an appimage for download, which contains the Export-menu.